# Python multiprocessing only uses 3 cores, totaling 130% CPU?

Tags: python

I have 24 cores on my machine, but I just can't get them all running. When I `top`, only 3 processes are running, and usually only one hits 100% CPU, the other two ~30%.

I've read all the related threads on this site, but still can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Pseudocode of how I used `pool` is as follows

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def Foo():
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    def myCallbackFun():
        pool.map(myFunc_wrapper, myArgs)
    optimization(callback=myCallbackFun) # scipy optimization that has a callback function.
```

Using `pdb`, I stopped before `optimization`, and checked I indeed have 24 workers.

[image]

But when I resume the program, `top` tells me I only have three Python processes running. Another thing is, when I `ctrl-c` to terminate my program, it has soooo many workers to interrupt (e.g., `PoolWorker-367`) -- I've pressing `ctrl-c` for minutes, but there are still workers out there. Shouldn't there be just 24 workers?

How to make my program use all CPUs?

Comment: `pool = mp.Pool(24)` and `pool.map(myFunc_wrapper, myArgs)` should do it

Comment: This is missing the `if __name__ == '__main__':` so that your script doesn't fork infinitely.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant parts of your real code it won't be possible to say much. You may be running into an IO bottleneck if your involved arguments are very big

Comment: @mata Indeed, it's due to IO bottleneck. I can fully use my cores when I try my best to reduce arguments passed. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers --

As @mata correctly points out,

> You may be running into an IO bottleneck if your involved arguments
>   are very big

This is indeed my case. Try to minimize the size of the arguments passed to each process.

Answer (score 1):

With multiprocessing Python starts new processes. With a script like yours it will fork infinitely. You need to wrap the script part of your module like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(24)
    pool.map(myFunc_wrapper, myArgs)
```

Comment: In the actual code, `pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())` was actually called in a function, so it's not really in `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Is this the issue?

Comment: Only if you have a script part in your code. If all your code is wrapped in functions it shouldn't be an issue. You should change your example though.

Comment: I see, where do you call Foo()?

Comment: The calling tree is like: ` if __name__ == '__main__':` calls `main()`, which calls `Bar()`, which calls `Foo()`.

Comment: Are you missing the underscores `__name__` and `'__main__'`?